# How to initialize unordered_set with default value 0 or -1?

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-set

How could I initialize the STL unordered_set with default value 0 or -1 without for loop init like how we do with an array,

```cpp
int arr[10] = {0};
```

Comment: It does not make any sense because the set can not have duplicate keys.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably confuse sets and arrays/vectors here:

A `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` only holds *unique* values. It can never contain any value more than once.

If you just want to initialize it with some values, you can do it likewise to an array:

- `std::unordered_set<int> set{0, -1};` creates a set with two values: 0 and -1
- `std::unordered_set<int> set{0, -1, -1, -1, -1};` does the same, since each unique value will only be contained *once*.